# Extracting Nouns and Verbs from Text

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to extract nouns, verbs separately in R package openNLP? 
I use the the tagPOS function which tags the sentence but what to do in case I want to extract verbs, nouns separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using an example: (this is to extract words tagged as /VBx, where x is any single character)

```
library("openNLP")

acq <- "Gulf Applied Technologies Inc said it sold its subsidiaries engaged in pipeline and terminal operations for 12.2 mln dlrs. The company said the sale is subject to certain post closing adjustments, which it did not explain. Reuter."

acqTag <- tagPOS(acq)

sapply(strsplit(acqTag,"[[:punct:]]*/VB.?"),function(x) sub("(^.*\\s)(\\w+$)", "\\2", x))

     [,1]                           
[1,] "said"                         
[2,] "sold"                         
[3,] "engaged"                      
[4,] "said"                         
[5,] "is"                           
[6,] "did"                          
[7,] " not/RB explain./NN Reuter./."
```

Ok, my regular expression needs some improvement in order to get rid of the last line in the result.

**EDIT**

An alternative could be to ignore rows containing a `space` character

```
sapply(strsplit(acqTag,"[[:punct:]]*/VB.?"),function(x) {res = sub("(^.*\\s)(\\w+$)", "\\2", x); res[!grepl("\\s",res)]} )
```

Comment: Thanks! gd047 :) it works... I was almost on the verge of using sapply for extracting but could not get a way how to do that. Thanks.