# extract nouns and verbs from a text dataframe and save it in two different dataframes in R

Tags: r, text, dataframe, extract, text-analysis

I have a text dataframe with only text columns. One of the columns is

> hw motorola scanner model  rssn  missing   issue  damaged power connectionif  serial   provide extended part numberrs fsr = short cable attached  wrist build type  rpcolleague    colin patterson contact number   ensure main depot id  selected   ensure   selected  correct model  position id    save  log

I have removed numbers, stopwords and punctuations from the text. I want to separate the nouns and verbs and put them in different dataframes.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970829/extracting-nouns-and-verbs-from-text) possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

That is not strictly a trivial task. You could load a library with the parts of speech for each word (e.g. OpenNLP -> [Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/openNLP.pdf)), but some of them may be either one part of speech or another depending upon context, so that makes this a much harder task programmatically to get perfect. Hope the OpenNPL package helps though.