# Extract verbs from sentence in R?

Tags: r, nlp

Please note that I am aware of [Extracting Nouns and Verbs from Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970829/extracting-nouns-and-verbs-from-text)
and it doesn't work for me because the function they use doesn't exist in `openNLP` package.

Here is my column of strings:

```
tibble(recipe_name = c("Easter Leftover Sandwich", "Pasta with Pesto Cream Sauce", 
"Herb Roasted Pork Tenderloin with Preserves", "Chicken Florentine Pasta", 
"Perfect Iced Coffee", "Easy Green Chile Enchiladas", "Krispy Easter Eggs", 
"Patty Melts", "Yum. Doughnuts!", "Buttery Lemon Parsley Noodles", 
"Roast Chicken", "Baked French Toast", "Yummy Slice-and-Bake Cookies", 
"Yummy Grilled Zucchini", "Chocolate Covered S’mores", "T-Bone Steaks with Hotel Butter", 
"Mango Margaritas!", "Tuscan Bean Soup with Shrimp", "Hoppin’ John", 
"Turkey Bagel Burger"))
```

I want to run an analysis that will find out all the verbs/nouns etc. in each of the names.

How can I do this in R?
I have checked `qdap` and `tm` packages but didn't find a function that will extract it.

Please advise how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get it by using udpipe_annotate function from udpipe library:

```
library(udpipe)
ud_model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(ud_model$file_model)
system.time(
  x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x = df$recipe_name, doc_id = df$id)
)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
abc <- c("NN","VB")
stats <- dplyr::filter(x,grepl(pattern = paste(abc, collapse = "|"), x = xpos, ignore.case = T))
```

you can also use list of word types from [this](https://cs.nyu.edu/grishman/jet/guide/PennPOS.html) list.