# Named entities with openNLP in R: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, r, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I've been experimenting with text minning/NLP/preprocessing in R. I've been trying to get NEE/NER to work on a simple piece of text.

### Here's the text

"Hocutt sells evidence-based ethics. It is strong medicine for an audience that prefers the old type, based on intuition, personal sensitivity, and a deep feeling for just what the right prescriptions must be. An audience that might paraphrase Hume, and deny the utility of evidence by intoning "No oughts from is's;" any more and your arguments will be dismissed as another naturalistic fallacy. Hume noted the ubiquitous segues from is's to oughts found in every moral disquisition that were made absent explanation: but "'tis necessary. . .that a reason should be given" (Hume, in Hocutt, 2000, p. 43). Most readers concluded "No oughts from is's" alone. Period. But, if not from is's, from whence do oughts emerge? What is left? Values? But those differ among individuals, and what they are and how they differ are themselves matters of fact. How do we construct/realize a universal ethics?; or even just a local one? Over-reaction to Hume's valid concern launched philosophers on a search for unmotivated Value."

```
library(methods)
library(rJava)
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
library(openNLPmodels.en)
library(coreNLP)
library(magrittr)
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
```

### Text in input tab

```
txt <- readLines(
        'stdin'
)
txt <- paste(
    txt,
    collapse = " "
)
txt <- as.String(
    txt
)

sntTkn <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
wrdTkn <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
posTag <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()

sWTkn <- annotate(
    txt,
    list(
        sntTkn,
        wrdTkn
))
sWTknPosTag <- annotate(
    txt,
    list(
    sntTkn,
    wrdTkn,
    posTag
))

persEnt <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(
    kind = "person"
)
locEnt <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(
    kind = 'location'
)
orgEnt <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(
    kind = 'organization'
)
dateEnt <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(
    kind = 'date'
)

pipeline <- list(
    sntTkn,
    wrdTkn,
    posTag,
    persEnt,
    locEnt,
    orgEnt,
    dateEnt
)
pip <- annotate(
    txt,
    pipeline
)
txtDoc <- AnnotatedPlainTextDocument(
    txt,
    pip
)

entities <- function(
    doc,
    kind
) {
    s <- doc$content
    a <- annotation(
        doc
    )
    if(
        hasArg(
            kind
        )
    ) {
        k <- sapply(
            a$features,
            '[[',
            "kind"
        )
        s[a[k == kind]]
    } else {
        s[a[a$type == 'entity']]
    }
}

entities(
    txtDoc,
    kind = "person"
)
```

### Output

```
Warning message:
In readLines("stdin") : incomplete final line found on 'stdin'
character(0)
```

I've been following the instructions in this video:

https://youtu.be/0lpQludiI-0

and I've been working with this app:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/r-programming-compiler/id1158038782

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When you run this on your phone `txt <- readLines( 'stdin')`, what does `>txt` show you?

Comment: @Chris It just outputs the text

Comment: @Chris It actually shows it as a vector, I believe. It displays after [1], the whole thing's in quotes and all *internal* quotation marks have backslashes in front of them. I put >txt *after* the as.String function. My bad.

Comment: Fair enough, had the same result. And the `txt <- paste(txt, collapse = " ")` seems equivalent to `txt <-txt[1]` and because it is character makes the as.String seemingly unnecessary. No need to mention that all the embedded special character make this less than a simple piece of text. Then, when exactly did the warning pop up in your process? As i had it `txt[5] was ""`, which would account for the warning, I think, Currently doing an upgrade that looks like it will take a few hours before I can source your packages. Don't know how the `as.String` handles trailing(2:5) but txt{1] might do it.

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear. txt <- txt[1] as your second statement, should clear off trailing empty texts(""). and then do your next stuff, tokenization and all.

Comment: @Chris Ok, did this. Same output. To be clear, `character(0)` isn't part of the warning message. It's what I get instead of the entities from `txt` displaying. The warning hasn't *seemed* to matter for anything, but maybe it actually does.

Comment: @Chris Thank you, btw.

Comment: Stepping through the `entities()` in `debugonce`, we see that we don't have entries that would match `kind`, found by stepping through to the assignment of a (and `n` again) `Browse[2]>  unique(a$type)
[1] "sentence" "word" `, so neither 'person' or 'entity' is there to satisfy the relationship leading to your result. All of which suggests that an annotation step is missing above that resolves to these 'named tokens'...Search further.

Comment: What if Hume and Horcutt weren't in the 'corpus'. Changing names to Newton and Emerson at least returned an entity (Emerson) in the changed cite. Altogether annoying so you might want to take a look at a [udpipe approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666096/extract-verbs-from-sentence-in-r) that gets you there quite nicely. HTH

Comment: @Chris I got the same result with *Newton* and *Emerson*. I have no clue, really, but I'm wondering if it's a character encoding issue. The text is from a 2003 PDF, and I cleaned it up manually before use with openNLP. I was getting some odd results using topic modeling package functions. I'll look at udpipe. Thanks again.

Comment: Always useful to look broadly at available libraries, and I think you'll find the whole indexing mechanism more straightforward. But it's not the encoding in this instance.